# Como obter o tipo da entidade de tipo genérico da interface superior?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, reflexão, genéricos

Eu tenho a seguinte situação:

```
public class MinhaClasse : IMinhaClasse<Carro>
{
      //...
}
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var foo = new MinhaClasse();
}
```

É possível conseguir o tipo de parâmetro genérico de IMinhaClasse através da minha instância foo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É possível saber qual é o tipo usando reflexão do tipo.

```
var tipos = foo.GetType()
    .GetInterfaces()
    .Where(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IMinhaClasse<>))
    .Select(x => x.GenericTypeArguments[0])
    .ToArray();
```

Isso vai retornar um array com o tipo `Carro` no caso do seu exemplo.

Mas suponhamos que um tipo qualquer implemente `IMinhaClasse<Carro>` e também `IMinhaClasse<Bicicleta>`, então o resultado será um array contendo `Carro` e `Bicicleta`.

**EDIT**

Para pegar os parâmetros declarados exatamente nas interfaces do tipo, sem considerar as herdadas, então teremos eliminar as herdadas depois de pegar todas:

```
var fooType = foo.GetType();
var tipos = fooType
    .GetInterfaces()
    .Where(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GenericTypeArguments.Length == 1)
    .Select(x => x.GenericTypeArguments[0])
    .Except((fooType.BaseType ?? typeof(object)).GetInterfaces())
    .ToArray();
```

**EDIT (2014/MAR/18)** Só compartilhando minhas descobertas:

Estive pesquisando a possibilidade de saber quais são as interfaces implementadas diretamente por um tipo, ***tal como declarado no código C#***, mas cheguei à conclusão de que isso não é possível.

Vou explicar com um exemplo:

```
interface IIndireta { }

interface IDireta { }

class Base : IIndireta { }

class ClasseA : Base, IDireta { }

class ClasseB : Base, IDireta, IIndireta { }
```

A conclusão é a seguinte: ***não é possível diferenciar a forma com que a `ClasseA` e a `ClasseB` implementam as suas interfaces via código***:

- Na declaração da `ClasseB` é colocada a interface `IIndireta` na lista de implementações, só que esta interface também é implementada pela classe `Base`, sendo que não é possível saber via reflexão, se a interface `IIndireta` foi declarada diretamente ou não.
- Na declaração da `ClasseA`, a interface `IIndireta` é implementada por herança da classe `Base`. Entretanto, via reflexão, não é possível saber que a `ClasseA` não possui em sua lista de implementações diretas a dita interface.

Comment: Consegui o resultado que eu queria, mas você saberia alguma forma de obter o resultado sem especificar o tipo (typeof(IMinhaClasse<>))?

Comment: Consegue sim, mas nesse caso você vai pegar também os tipos de interfaces como `IEnumerable<xxx>` ou quaisquer outras genéricas, que podem não ter nada a ver... é isso mesmo?