# Quais as diferenças entre Tipos Genéricos em C# e em Java?

Tags: java, c#, característica-linguagem, genéricos

Eu estudei Java há bastante tempo e estou bem familiarizado com o funcionamento de **tipos genéricos** nessa linguagem: sei que só existem em tempo de compilação, que sofrem *type erasure* ao final da mesma (de modo que no tempo de execução essas informações não estão disponíveis), e tenho uma certa noção das [dificuldades ao se aplicar polimorfismo em tipos genéricos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8679/215).

Agora estou aprendendo C#, e reparei que embora essa linguagem use notação semelhante (`Tipo<TipoGenerico>`) a semântica não parece ser a mesma. Por exemplo, ao ver [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9580/215) entendi que o runtime do C# guarda a informação dos tipos genéricos em vez de descartá-la, diferentemente do Java, isso está correto? Além disso, nunca vi um exemplo em C# que utilizasse "coringas" (*wildcards*) como `Tipo<? extends TipoGenerico>`. Isso é possível (ou mesmo necessário) nessa linguagem?

Por fim, C# suporta métodos individuais (e não somente classes) genéricos? Se sim, qual a sintaxe equivalente dessa construção em Java:

```
public <T> void metodo(T parametro1, List<T> parametro2) {
```

Se houver algum detalhe adicional que mereça destaque, ou talvez algum material de referência para aprender mais, também será bem-vindo.

Comment: Esse `public <T> void metodo(T parametro1, List<T> parametro2) {` é do Java... e teria como finalidade fazer o que?

Comment: @tchicotti Por exemplo, fazer uma operação entre `parametro1` e `parametro2` onde não importa qual é o seu tipo, mas importa que eles estejam relacionados (ex.: insere `parametro1` na lista `parametro2`).

Comment: @tchicotti isso acontece quando se deseja declarar um genéricos apenas à nível do método, ou seja, a classe não declara genéricos

Comment: Eu entendi, e é possível, só não respondi dpois, pq ja teve respostas completas

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### Comparação C# vs Java

> C# guarda a informação dos tipos genéricos em vez de descartá-la, diferentemente do Java, isso está correto

Sim, no C# não ocorre a *Type Erasure* que ocorre em Java. No java, internamente, o compilador descarta o fato de que é `MinhaClasseEspecifica` e trata como `Object`, fazendo os casts necessários para a sua classe específica.

Já no C#, o compilador JIT (Just-In-Time) internamente constrói uma classe específica com o tipo `T` utilizado. Se você utiliza um objeto `Tipo<string>`, por exemplo, internamente ele cria uma classe onde todos os `T` são string.

Do ponto de vista de desempenho, o que o C# está fazendo é mais performático, pois não precisa de casts pra lá e pra cá.

Segundo o próprio Anders Hejlsberg :

> Por exemplo, com generics em Java, você na verdade não obtém a eficiência em execução que eu comentei, porque quando você compila uma classe genérica em Java, o compilador retira o parâmetro do tipo e substitui tudo por Object.
>
> ...
>
> O IL e os metadados contém informações adicionais de que existe um `type parameter`, claro, mas em princípio, um tipo genérico compila da mesma forma que qualquer outro tipo compilaria. Em tempo de execução, quando sua aplicaçao faz a primeira referencia para um `List<int>`, por exemplo, o sistema olha se alguém já pediu um `List<int>`. Se ninguém o fez, ele alimenta o JIT com o IL e os metadados para o tipo `List<T>` e o argumento do tipo `int`. O JITer produz o código nativo específico para aquele tipo no momento que é necessário. Em Runtime.

Fonte: http://www.artima.com/intv/generics2.html

(Tradução Livre)

### Wildcards / Type Constraints em Generics

> Além disso, nunca vi um exemplo em C# que utilizasse "coringas" (wildcards) como `Tipo<? extends TipoGenerico>`

Em C# seria assim:

```
class Classe<T> where T : TipoEspecifico
```

Existem vários [Type Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx), siga o link para ver. (Está em inglês)

### Métodos Genéricos

> Por fim, C# suporta métodos individuais (e não somente classes) genéricos? Se sim, qual a sintaxe equivalente dessa construção em Java:

Basicamente troque o `<T>` de lugar

```
T FazerAlgoComT<T>(T obj) { ... }
```

Lembrando que você pode usar os [Type Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) (where blablabla) nos métodos também.

Answer (score 20):

> Além disso, nunca vi um exemplo em C# que utilizasse "coringas"
>   (wildcards) como `Tipo<? extends TipoGenerico>`. Isso é possível (ou
>   mesmo necessário) nessa linguagem?

Sim, é possível limitar o parâmetro genérico a um tipo especifico da seguinte forma:

```
public class MinhaClasse<TEntidade> where TEntidade : MinhaClassePai{}
```

> Por fim, C# suporta métodos individuais (e não somente classes)
>   genéricos? Se sim, qual a sintaxe equivalente dessa construção em
>   Java:

Você pode utilizar métodos genéricos desde que os parâmetros genéricos estejam presentes na Classe ou no método, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
public TEntidade MeuMetodo<TEntidade>(TEntidade meuObjeto){}
```

Caso você não queira definir o parâmetro genérico em seu método, você pode utilizar o da classe:

```
 public class MinhaClasse<TEntidade> where TEntidade : MinhaClassePai
{
    public TEntidade MeuMetodo(TEntidade meuObjeto){}
}
```

Quanto a sua primeira questão, @ConradClark a respondeu de forma clara e objetiva.

Answer (score 18):

As perguntas foram respondidas nas duas respostas postadas até agora. Vou acrescentar algo extra que ainda não foi dito.

Em C# a concretização do tipo ocorre em *runtime* e não em tempo de compilação como é o caso  do C++, por exemplo. Em C++ o **compilador** gera uma implementação concreta sempre que um tipo diferente for utilizado.

Uma das coisas que se reclama muito em C++ é que se o código utilizar muitos tipos concretos com um `template` você terá uma enorme *code bloat* porque cada tipo concreto gerará um código diferente da classe ou método gabaritado. Java não sofre deste problema porque no fundo tudo é `object` e então só há uma implementação concreta para este tipo.

O código distribuído do C# funciona mais ou menos da mesma forma que o Java. A concretização da implementação só ocorrerá na memória. Já é um ganho, mas ainda teria um trambolho de implementações duplicadas na memória. Note que o CLR, a máquina virtual do .NET, entende o código genérico que o compilador emite. A JVM não sabe fazer isto.

Mas o CLR é mais esperto que isto. Ela cria implementações concretas para cada tipo por valor, as chamadas `structs` - que o Java, ainda não tem, e por isto os tipos primitivos precisam ser [encaixotados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/160914/101) - mas para os tipos por referência só uma instância disto é criada para segurar uma referência qualquer. Afinal todas estas implementações concretas precisam ser criadas por causa da diferença semântica de valor ou referência e por causa do tamanho do dado. Os tipos por referência funcionam todos de forma idêntica e o tamanho é sempre o tamanho do ponteiro, então não tem motivo para existir uma instância da implementação para cada tipo por referência.

Em C++ não é possível fazer o mesmo porque o `template` é mais flexível e cada implementação pode ser diferente, inclusive tendo comportamentos especializados.

Outro ponto que foi falado é sobre o polimorfismo. Alguns consideram até mesmo que a *genericidade* permite dispensar o polimorfismo se a linguagem for talhada para isto. Veja isto:

```
T Metodo<T>(T obj) where T : TipoPai {
    return obj.ChamaAlgo(); //Qual "ChamaAlgo()" será executado?
}
```

O método `ChamaAlgo()` a ser chamado será aquele dependente do tipo de `obj`. E este tipo pode ser `TipoPai` ou pode ser `TipoFilho1`, `TipoFilho2`, `TipoNeto`, etc., ou seja qualquer tipo descendente de `TipoPai`. Note que `ChamarAlgo()` não precisaria ser virtual para isto funcionar nesta linguagem hipotética.

Outro aspecto que deve ser falado é que um dos motivos que os *wildcards* do Java foram introduzidos era permitir co e contra variância de tipos no **uso** dele. Em C# isto é obtido na **declaração** do tipo com `in` e `out`.

```
class exemplo<out T> //covariante

class exemplo<in T>  //contravariante
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Generics/Hypothetical.cs).

Answer (score 12):

Do meu ponto de vista, a principal diferença é que, em Java, você pode entender que o propósito das classes genéricas é somente de fornecer um certo nível de segurança no momento da compilação, "garantindo" até certo ponto que o seu programa não vai gerar uma exceção relacionada à incompatibilidade de tipos em tempo de execução. Ao mesmo tempo, isso alavanca o reuso de código.

Em outras linguagens, como C#, poderíamos entender que o propósito é gerar variações "concretas" de classes a partir de uma classe base.

Além disso, algumas comparações realizadas em outras respostas não são exatamente "justas". Sobre o desempenho, por exemplo, em Java você não ganha ou perde praticamente nada em desempenho ao usar uma classe genérica. A diferença será que, ao não usar genéricos você precisa fazer *casts* explícitos.

Em tese, Java seria sempre mais "lento" nesse ponto, no sentido de que não possui essa otimização específica. A única forma de otimização seria replicar o código em classes não genéricas. Mas se for para fazer uma comparação entre as linguagens, vários outros critérios deveriam ser considerados. Por exemplo, fato de não haver esse tipo específico de otimização não significa que, só para efeito de exemplo, o *cast* do Java possa ser mais rápido do que a chamada direta em C#.

Um *trade-off* que foi mencionado apenas implicitamente em outras linguagens, é que o Java não consome mais memória para as classes genéricas. Não creio ser um ponto muito delicado, mas o C# vai consumir mais memória proporcionalmente ao número de classes genéricas que você implementar.

Por fim, um dos grandes entraves para qualquer evolução nesse ponto na linguagem Java é que em geral há uma grande preocupação com compatibilidade. É uma decisão de projeto que não agrada muita gente, mas manter o código em *runtime* inalterado economizou muito dinheiro às empresas que não precisaram reescrever aplicações para adaptá-las às novas versões da Máquina Virtual Java.