# Método que retorna classe pai para classe filha

Tags: c#, .net, método, genéricos, polimorfismo

Tenho as seguintes classes:

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
}

public class Cliente : Pessoa
{
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
}
public class Funcionario : Pessoa
{
    public int FuncionarioId { get; set; }
}
```

Criei o seguinte método:

```
public Pessoa Teste(Pessoa pessoa)
{
    // Bloco lógico
    return pessoa;
}
```

O que eu gostaria de fazer agora era enviar um `Funcionario` ou `Cliente` para o método `Teste` e obtê-los de volta com suas propriedades de `Pessoa` alteradas.

O problema é que ao usar:

```
var func = new Funcionario();
func = Teste(func);
```

Não funciona, pois minha variável `func` é do tipo `Funcionario`, e o retorno no método `Teste` retorna uma `Pessoa`. Mas já que `Funcionario` herda de `Pessoa` não existe alguma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: `public Pessoa Teste<Pessoa>(Pessoa pessoa) { }` assim ao menos não deu erro de compilação, mas o por que é a grande pergunta!

Comment: Eu não entendi qual é o objetivo para decidir o que é o melhor para você.

Comment: `ClienteId` e `FuncionarioId` não são necessários. Você pode removê-los dos *Models* derivados.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De uma maneira geral a resposta do Andrew funciona, afinal se você tem certeza que passou um `Funcionario` para o método então sabe que fazer um *cast* do objeto retornado para `Funcionario` funcionará. Sem essa certeza isto seria um perigo.

Uma forma mais "moderna" de fazer isso é o que diz a resposta do Gabriel Katakura. Fazendo um [método genérico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/101) você já garante que o tipo retornado será do tipo que você passou para o método, assim não precisa fazer um *cast* e é mais seguro.

```
public T Teste<T>(T pessoa) where T : Pessoa {
    //faz o que deseja aqui
    return pessoa;
}
```

Chamada:

```
var func = new Funcionario();
func = Teste(func); //ele infere, se não fosse possível chamaria Teste<Funcionario>(func)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Generics/Employee.cs).

Note que nesse caso o compilador gerará um método especializado que receberá um objeto de um tipo qualquer e retornará um objeto do mesmo tipo. Isso é definido pelo parâmetro `T` que é uma super variável de tipo. Eu disse que recebe um objeto qualquer, mas não é bem assim. Tem uma restrição dizendo que o `T` deve ser qualquer tipo, desde que ele seja uma `Pessoa`, portanto tipos derivados valem, outros não. Mais detalhes está na pergunta *linkada* acima.

Quando compila esse código é como se tivesse escrito:

```
public Funcionario Teste(Funcionario pessoa) {
    //faz o que deseja aqui
    return pessoa;
}
```

Mas não precisou escrever, essa é a beleza da genericidade. O compilador adapta o seu método para cada tipo que você usar. Será definido pelo uso do método. Isso é chamado *client site*, ou *consumer site*.

Obviamente você ainda não poderá fazer nada específico de um objeto `Funcionario` ou `Cliente`, só pode fazer coisas disponíveis em `Pessoa`. Se deseja fazer algo específico que só um `Funcionario` pode então deve fazer algo com `Funcionario` mesmo.

Comment: Não sei se vale a pena citar, mas essa vantagem do compilador ocorre no caso do C#... algumas linguagens o uso do generics é somente um Açúcar Sintático para disfarçar o uso de object com downcast/upcast, como o caso de Java, que tem Type Erasure. Ou seja, em Java a vantagem é somente em alto nível.

Comment: Bem, dando uma olhada nos links da resposta linkada, tem um que explica justamente isso. Pode ignorar este comentário, haha.
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10032/quais-as-diferen%C3%A7as-entre-tipos-gen%C3%A9ricos-em-c-e-em-java

Comment: @GabrielKatakura não serve aqui, mas é sempre uma informação útil. tem alguns detalhes extras no C#. Eu simplifiquei e falei que ele gera um método especizlizado. Isto não é bem verdade, ele é mais inteligente que isto. Ele usa o mesmo para todos os tipos de referência e evita o *cast* por já ter a informação que tudo vai dar certo, afinal em certas circunstâncias o *cast* é só informação para o compilador e não faz nada.

Answer (score 3):

Basta usar generics para isso (resposta curta, estou sem tempo, desculpe):

```
public TPessoa Teste<TPessoa>(TPessoa pessoa)
    where TPessoa : Pessoa
{
    return pessoa;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você ja tentou fazer um casting?

```
var func = new Funcionario();
func = (Funcionario)Teste(func);
```

Uma vez que Funcionario também é uma Pessoa um casting simples deve funcionar.