# Como é a sintaxe de generics em C# comparado ao Java?

Tags: java, c#, característica-linguagem, sintaxe

Sou um desenvolvedor Java estudando C# e me deparei com a seguinte diferença entre as duas linguagens:

> https://nerdparadise.com/programming/csharpforjavadevs
>
> ### Generics
>
> Generics are much less fiddly in C#. Partially because they are both a compile-time and run-time concept. There is no diamond syntax (e.g. new ArrayList<>();) in C# which may sound horrific, but it's really not that bad. As a bonus, primitives are valid types for generics. So you can have a List instead of an awkward List that suddenly implies nullability.
>
> Invoking methods that require generics as parameters are done between the method name and the parenthesis as opposed to between the dot and the method name. Basically constructors and methods in C# use the same convention whereas Java used different syntax for generics for the constructor and methods.

Não entendi o último parágrafo. A que ele se refere? Segue tentativa de tradução:

> Invocar métodos que requerem genéricos como parâmetros é feito entre o nome do método e os parênteses, em oposição a entre o ponto e o nome do método. Basicamente construtores e métodos em C# usam a mesma convenção enquanto que Java usou sintaxes diferentes para genéricos no construtor e nos métodos.

Comment: Isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10032/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150181/101?

Comment: Na verdade o título está mal formulado, a dúvida é referente a uma informação presente num parágrafo específico, mas não sei se dá para responder em poucas palavras. Vou comparar com as outras perguntas.

Comment: O parágrafo diz que em C# você chama um método genérico assim `MeuMetodo<int, string, char>(a, b, c, d)`

Comment: @LINQ Entendi! Valeu!

Comment: @Piovezan Eu tava escrevendo uma resposta, mas não consigo lembrar como é em Java 

Comment: @LINQ `meuMetodo(<List> lista, <Map> mapa) { ... }`

Comment: declara os tipos separados dos argumentos?

Comment: Nossa, viajei na maionese. `meuMetodo(T1 lista, Map<T1> mapa)`... acho que agora está certo... e declara o tipo paramétrico `T1` junto ao nome da classe `public class MinhaClasse<T1> { ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O segundo parágrafo tá dizendo que você pode fazer o seguinte,

```
IDataReader dr = conn.ExecuteQuery(query);
while (dr.Read())
{
    int id = DBHelper.Read<int>(dr["id"]);
    ...
}
```

Veja como eu chamei `T DBHelper.Read<T>(object)`. Passei o tipo genérico entre o nome do método e o abre-parênteses.

Answer (score 1):

C# e Java generics são bem parecidos, porém diferem mesmo é em tempo de compilação e runtime, enquanto Java resolve os genericos apenas em tempo de compilação, ou seja, ele não cria realmente um tipo para cada generico, é apenas um tipo que o compilador faz açucar sintatico para parecer generico, mas por traz dos panos é apenas um monte de casts, enfim, em C#, isso é resolvido em tempo de compilação pela criação de tipos, exemplo, List difere de List, e assim por diante, isso acarreta em melhor desempenho em relação a genericos em C#.